# How to start Teamviewer minimised to System Tray, when "Close To Tray Menu" option is not working

Tags: windows-10, teamviewer

Currently there is a bug in Team-viewer that it opens in full window on windows start up, and no available options on the internet can get it to close. It is reported by many users.

Aim: Normal service startup, on login, team-viewer is minimized to tray.

Many users are having this problem; here are some examples. [One](https://community.teamviewer.com/English/discussion/comment/76367#Comment_76367), [Two](https://community.teamviewer.com/English/discussion/101828/start-teamviewer-minimised), [Three](https://community.teamviewer.com/English/discussion/37768/why-doesnt-teamviewer-minimize-when-closed-anymore), [Four](https://community.teamviewer.com/English/discussion/76178/start-teamviewer-minimized), [Five](https://community.teamviewer.com/English/discussion/28634/startup-teamviewer-in-windows-minim)

Answer (score 1):

*Teamviewer has a service and a program. This will close the program on system login of any user within a few seconds of login, the service will still be running and in the system tray, not instantaneous but faster then user system startup folder.*

***How to make the batch file:***

- Open Start.
- Search for Notepad
- Open, write script

---

```
@echo off 
taskkill /IM "TeamViewer.exe" /F
```

---

- save as
- start-min-teamviewer.bat
- click "save type as" and change to  `All Files (*.*)`
- Save to: `C:\Users\NetworkAdmin\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs`
- Or your own location
  [image: Example of Teamviewer close script]

***Create task scheduler (faster then startup folder).***

Press the Windows + R keys, (opens run Run), and then type taskschd.msc

- On the right click `create task`
- Name: Teamviewer Minimize To Tray (in the example its just `minteam`)
- Tick Run with highest privileges

[image: Run with highest privileges]

- In the trigger window, set to At login of any user

[image]

- Under actions tab: New-->  Start a program --> `"C:\Users\NetworkAdmin\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\start-min-teamviewer.bat"` into the `program\script` box
- OK
- Ok done.
- Logoff, Logon, and should close within a few seconds of opening.